# Cannot understand why this Java program produces such output

Tags: java, output

Here is the code :

```
class Value
{
    public int i = 15;
}
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.first();
    }
    public void first()
    {
        int i = 5;
        Value v = new Value();
        v.i = 25;
        second(v, i);
        System.out.println(v.i);
    }
    public void second(Value v, int i)
    {
        i = 0;
        v.i = 20;
        Value val = new Value();
        v =  val;
        System.out.println(v.i + " " + i);
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why this code prints

```
15 0
20
```

on the console.

Why is it not

```
15 0
15
```

?

Comment: Java is pass by value.

Comment: No Java pass object argument by reference nd primitiv type by value

Comment: @user43968 But you get the value of the reference, so `v = val` changes the reference value stored as `v` to be the same reference value as the one `val` holds. It does not deference anything.

Comment: @user43968 you are wrong, Java (and C/C++) is strictly pass by value. But if the value that you pass is a reference, the referenced object is the same from both the original and copied references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in Java is passed by value.  In this `first` method

```
public void first()
{
    int i = 5;
    Value v = new Value();
    v.i = 25;
    second(v, i);
    System.out.println(v.i);
}
```

you pass the value of the reference stored in `v` (which points to a `Value` object with an `i` field with value `15`) to `second`.

```
public void second(Value v, int i)
{
    i = 0;
    v.i = 20;
    Value val = new Value();
    v =  val;
    System.out.println(v.i + " " + i);
}
```

It dereferences the reference value to find a `Value` object and changes its `i` field value to `20`. You then create a new `Value` object with its `i` field value initialized to 15. That's what you're printing

```
15 0
```

The method returns and `first` prints the value of the object the local variable `v` is referencing, ie.

```
20
```

Comment: "which points to a Value object with an i field with value 15"... but the value of i field is changed to 25 in first()...

Comment: @skrtbhtngr And it is changed back to `20` in `second`.

Comment: but in second(), the reference variable v is assigned a new object referred to by val... so that changes the value of v.i to 15 (default)... then, doesn't it reflect in first()?
PS: I'm a beginner.

Comment: @skrtbhtngr After `first` does `v.i = 25`, it passes `v` to `second`. In `second`, you do `v.i = 20`. This `v` is referencing the same object as `first` was. Only after that is it reassigned to a new object in `v = val`.

Comment: OK... lets start again... v=val does change the value of v.i to 15...right? Then, when the function call returns to first() and value of v.i is printed, 15 should be printed as v.i=20 was overridden by  v=val... but it is not happening??

Comment: @skrtbhtngr `first` creates a new `Value` object, let's call it `A`. It sets `A.i` to `25`. It then passes `A` to `second`. `second` does `v.i = 20`. At this point in the code `v` is referencing `A`, so it does `A.i = 20`. Then `second` creates a new `Value` object, call it `B`. It then assigns `B` to `v` in `v = val`. So `v` **is no longer** referencing `A`, it is referencing `B`. This does absolutely nothing to `A`.